# VS Code not showing up on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I am an utter beginner. I downloaded VS Code.
To start with my first html project, I opened file explorer and created a text document "index.html"
Then I opened it up with chrome, and VS Code. I started writing on Vs Code but whatever I wrote did not appear on the Chrome file.

What is the solution?

Comment: After typing code in VS Code, you should CTRL + S. And then index.html file double click.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install the extension called "Live Server" (press `Ctrl + Shift + X` to open the extensions tab). Then whenever you save (shortcut `Ctrl + S`) your file will be updated.